# Can I arrange my light fixtures in a branch configuration or must they be in a linear daisy chain?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I'm tapping an old ceiling light in the center of the room to power 4 new recessed lights.  Can I arrange the new lights in a branch configuration where Light #1 connects to Light #2 and Light #1 also connects to Light #3?   Or do I need to run my wires so that the lights connect in a linear daisy chain series L1 to L2 to L3 to L4?  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You're keeping the junction box accessible, correct? It needs to be part of the light fixture or visible with a cover plate, not covered over with drywall.

Comment: Yes, I've kept it visible with a cover plate.  Thanks!

Comment: I do not know the exact requirements so this is why it is a comment rather than an answer. It depends on how big the box is that you are using and how many wires enter the box. I believe the over simplified rule of thumb is the bigger the box, the more wires you can have enter it. There are shallow and deep boxes to help accommodate the rule.

Comment: Why not go from the existing box, to L2, then L1, then L3, and finally L4?

Comment: I wanted to cut the least amount of access holes in the ceiling drywall and drill the least amount of holes through the ceiling joists.

Comment: I would agree with Tester101. If the distance to L2 is the same as L1 then you will not save any cable going to L1 first. By going to L2 first you can limit the numer of wires in each splice in each box to 2 plus the fixture wires in those boxes. You will have the same number of holes through the joists either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to run power in a "daisy chain," you can branch from one point to several.

With the sketch you have, switched power coming in at L1, and branching out in two directions, you'll probably have no trouble finding a box large enough to accommodate the wires.